# Centering images horizontally in a shiny fluidRow

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny

Is it possible to centre three images in one row within the shiny ui fluidPage AND have the width of each image fixed at 300px? To get:

[image]

One idea I had was to use splitLayout and somehow insert an image as a function of window width but I am not sure how to acheive this. I understand you can use splitLayout to set the images as a % of window, however I specifically want the middle image to be 300px.

```
fluidPage(fluidRow(
    splitLayout(cellWidths = c("34%", 300, "34%"), cellArgs = list(style = "padding: 0px"), style = "border: 0px; padding: 0px;",
       div(img(src="image1", height=300, width=300, align="right"),
       div(img(src="image2", height=300, width=300, align="center"),
       div(img(src="image3", height=300, width=300, align="left")), ...
```

So the problem is I get images are off centre:

[image]

But when I set the middle cell as 33% say then the gap between the images is too large.

```
splitLayout(cellWidths = c("34%", "33%", "34%"), cellArgs = list(style = "padding: 0px"), style = "border: 0px; padding: 0px;",
div(img(src="image1", height=300, width=300, align="right"),
div(img(src="image2", height=300, width=300, align="center"),
div(img(src="image3", height=300, width=300, align="left"))
```

[image]

So what I am after is `cellWidths = c((windowWidth-300)/2, 300, (windowWidth-300)/2)` but I am not sure how to extract the windowWidth.

Comment: have you tried column argument? The total width of window is 12. So you can probable leave 1/1.5 on either side and fit the images on remaining 9 left.

Comment: I have but cannot find a way to make this work for my problem. As I said to Pork Chop, I would really want all three images centred together within the column, as though they were one object (I do not want to make one giant image as I am using them as activeLinks).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to fix it using the column function, I was simply missing the `align="center"` argument paired with the removal of the width argument in the style. For example:

```
library(shiny)

server = function(input, output, session) {}

ui <- fluidPage(fluidRow(
         column(12, align="center",
                div(style="display: inline-block;",img(src="image1", height=300, width=300)),
                div(style="display: inline-block;",img(src="image2", height=300, width=300)),
                div(style="display: inline-block;",img(src="image3", height=300, width=300))))
)


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)

server = function(input, output, session) {}

ui <- fluidPage(fluidRow(
  #Change column(x, for desired width
  column(6,
         div(style="display: inline-block; width: 33%;",img(src="https://cran.r-project.org/Rlogo.svg", height=300, width=300)),
         div(style="display: inline-block; width: 33%;",img(src="https://cran.r-project.org/Rlogo.svg", height=300, width=300)),
         div(style="display: inline-block; width: 33%;",img(src="https://cran.r-project.org/Rlogo.svg", height=300, width=300))))
)


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: Kind of, what I am really after though is the middle image centred and the images to the left/right imediately to the left/right without any gaps or padding (i.e. all three images centred like in image 1 of the question). The problem with column and splitLayout, as far as I can tell, is that once you increase the window size the images will be dragged apart as the columns or div widths become wider (as in image 3). But without column or splitLayout the images default to left-aligned.