# How to align elements in a shiny tab panel

Tags: r, shiny, documentation

I would like to set height of a tab panel and to align elements horizontaly in it.
I didn't find how to proceed reading the tabpanel documentation :

https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.12.1/tabPanel.html

For example, if I put two side by side images produced by the solution here:

[Centering images horizontally in a shiny fluidRow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47551311/centering-images-horizontally-in-a-shiny-fluidrow)

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)

server = function(input, output, session) {}

ui <- fluidPage(fluidRow(
  #Change column(x, for desired width
  column(6,
         div(style="display: inline-block; width: 33%;",img(src="https://cran.r-project.org/Rlogo.svg", height=300, width=300)),
         div(style="display: inline-block; width: 33%;",img(src="https://cran.r-project.org/Rlogo.svg", height=300, width=300)),
         div(style="display: inline-block; width: 33%;",img(src="https://cran.r-project.org/Rlogo.svg", height=300, width=300))))
)


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

How can I make sure that the images are aligned if they don't have the same height?

[image]

Thanks for your help

Comment: all the widgets, tables, graphs, etc. are UI elements. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: I mean you can see from the examples on that page the types of things you can pass there. It just has to be some shiny UI element. What exactly are you trying to do? It would be better if you asked a specific programming question rather than just asking for documentation (which is basically an off-topic request and a reason to close a question).

Comment: comments has to be short. I will add more to the question in a minute.