# How do I center a markdown (.Rmd) file in a {shiny} application?

Tags: r, shiny, format, r-markdown, markdown

I am trying to center my markdown documents that I am including in a `shiny` app.

Minimal example: Using a file called `markdown_file.Rmd` which has this text in it:

```
---
output: html_document
---

# Test file

This is some text.
```

and a very basic `shiny` app:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- navbarPage(
    title = "Test app",
    tabPanel(
        "First tab",
        mainPanel(
            fluidPage(
                includeMarkdown('markdown_file.Rmd')
            )
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

We can see that the markdown document automatically aligns to the left in the app. I would like for it to be in the center of the page, but for the text in the document to still align left. I've tried the top answer here, [Centering images horizontally in a shiny fluidRow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47551311/centering-images-horizontally-in-a-shiny-fluidrow), but it just aligns my text in the markdown document to be centered, leaving the actual document on the left of the page in `shiny`. Any help here much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This got mine to about 3/8 to the center of the page. let me know how this works for you. You can also add html in Shiny if you know HTML to organize your output. remember shiny only has 12 columns

```
fluidPage(
    column(12, align="center",
    includeMarkdown('markdown_file.Rmd'))
```

But if I do

```
fluidPage(column(8, align="right",
                includeMarkdown('markdown_file.Rmd')
            ))
```

I actually get a more centered Rmarkdown